# ffmpeg mp4 video is not playing on html5 video player on browser (corrupt format)

Tags: php, ffmpeg, html5-video, codec

I am executing the following command to insert a watermark on the video and output as a mp4 format but that format is not playing on the browser by html5 video player.

```
$video_url = '../../../uploads/myvideo.mp4';
$watermarked = '../../../uploads/watermarked_video.mp4';
exec("ffmpeg -i $video_url -vf \"movie='sos.png', crop=iw:ih:0:0:dar [img]; [in] [img] overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2 [out]\" -vcodec mpeg4 -f avi $watermarked");  //creating water marked video
```

if i download it to my local machine then its playing perfectly on the player.

is there any syntax problem?

Comment: What's with watermarked videos? I have seen 3 ques within 1 min! Anyways , does your web player supports ffmpeg ?

Comment: no i am generating a mp4 video with a watermark on it. but not playing with the html5 video player on browser

Comment: Does your web (html5 player) supports ffmpeg format to play without installing anything else?

Comment: no i think its not support ffmpeg, But what is the relation with player and ffmpeg. player will play the mp4 video which i am generating with ffmpeg command execution. the player is playing the video with a saved video on the server (with a url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output format is not quite right. There are two factors to consider here:

1. The "container format" or the "file format", which is the way the whole file is arranged (e.g. AVI, MOV/QuickTime, WebM, Ogg)
2. The "codec", which is the algorithm used to compress and uncompress the video and audio data within the container. Most files will have two codecs: one for audio (e.g. AAC, Vorbis, MP3, Opus) and one for video (e.g. H.264, VP8, Theora).

ffmpeg supports reading and writing many different formats and codecs, as does VLC player. QuickTime does too, but not quite as many. Browsers, however, are much more picky. You're saving your file in an "AVI" container format, which browsers don't support. And you should probably use `libx264` as the codec, which will output H.264 video and is a little more widely used and reliable than `mpeg4` which will output MPEG-4 Part 2 video.

Try this:

```
$video_url = '../../../uploads/myvideo.mp4';
$watermarked = '../../../uploads/watermarked_video.mp4';
exec("ffmpeg -i $video_url -i sos.png -filter_complex \"[1:v]crop=iw:ih:0:0:dar [img]; [0:v] [img] overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2 [out]\" -map \"[out]\" -map 0:a -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy $watermarked");  //creating water marked video
```

- I've removed the `-f` parameter because ffmpeg can infer the format from the output file extension.
- The movie filter has been removed from the example because it is not needed.
- `-vf` was replaced in this example with `-filter_complex`. See [simple](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Simple-filtergraphs) and [complex](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Complex-filtergraphs) filtering to see what the differences are.
- The audio in this example will be [stream copied](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) with `-acodec copy` instead of re-encoded.